# Data cannot saved in django formview

Tags: django, forms, templates

I'm going to receive data and save it using form and save it. But I can't get any result. Let me know what I'm doing wrong.

I set up a model. And I wrote a form to get the input. Forms.Form was used. At first, I used modelform, but I wrote it like this because there seemed to be no difference.

Is label important in the form? You can't get the data value because you can't connect the label?

heeelp!

```
models.py
class PayHistory(models.Model):
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    package_recommandation_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    package_payment_date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

```
forms.py
class PackageForm(forms.Form):
    package_recommandation_date = forms.CharField(label='package_recommandation_date')
    package_payment_date = forms.CharField(label='package_payment_date')
    ...
## i changed like this(1)
class PackageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PayHistory
        fields = ['package_recommandation_date', 'package_payment_date']
```

```
views.py
class PackageView(FormView):
    model = PayHistory
    template_name = 'branches/package-create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('/')
    form_class = PackageForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form = form.save(commit=False) 
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

### I realize what you mean. I changed it like this(2) and it was saved in DB.
def form_valid(self, form):
        data = PayHistory()
        data.package_recommandation_date = form.cleaned_data['package_recommandation_date']
        data.package_payment_date = form.cleaned_data['package_payment_date']
        data.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

```
# HTML
{% block content %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="table-content">
        <!-- 검색 -->
        <table border="0">
            <tr class="input-tr">

                <td><input type="date" class="input1" name="package_recommandation_date"
                    value="{{ form.package_recommandation_date.value|default_if_none:'' }}" required>
                    </td>

                    <td><input type="date" class="input2" name="package_payment_date"
                            value="{{ form.package_payment_date.value|default_if_none:'' }}">
                    </td>
                    ...
                    <td><button type="submit" class="input-button input16">적용</button></td>
```

```
# static/js
const package_recommandation_date = document.querySelector("package_recommandation_date");
const package_payment_date = document.querySelector("package_payment_date");

console.info(package_recommandation_date, package_payment_date)

#output
-> null null
```

Comment: of course this won't work because you are not actually saving the data in the database the only way to save the data directly inside the db is when you used `forms.ModelForm`  refer to this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-modelform-create-form-from-models/ . if you want to save the data using `forms.Form`  like you are doing here then you have to save it manually by calling the model and getting data from the form you can read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms for more informations.

Comment: I didn't understand what you said properly. So what should I add? Do you want me to add cleaned_data? @Thierno Amadou Sow

Comment: I realize what you mean. I changed code and that code was saved in my database. thx bro!